# How do I restore the default repositories?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I accidentally messed up my apt-sources list in raspberian n my Raspberry PI 3.

my distro is:

```
Linux host 4.4.9-v7+ #884 SMP Fri May 6 17:28:59 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is there any way to get back the default `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

I never changed it in the past...

Comment: What's stopping you from checking the contents of the file in the original image and using a text editor to copy that content to the current `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @techraf It's the only Raspberry PI I have with this version of Raspberian on it.

Comment: You don't need a Raspberry Pi to check what's on the image you used. You can just mount the image on any machine and check. What is "Raspberian", btw?

Comment: The only necessary content is `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi` and AFAIK you can manage it through the menu of GUI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d contains the file

raspi.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```